# IntegrityError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

I'm trying to parse the following parameters into `cursor.execute`:

```
sql_insert = 'insert into sms_messaging (result_sms, msgid, msgparts) values (:1, :2, :3)'
smsreport_text_new = ('success', '2D67C865FB6FA25A9261C75E8D2F0F2B ', 1)

cursor.execute(sql_insert, smsreport_text_new)
```

Afterwards I'm receiving the following error message:

```
IntegrityError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ADAUTH"."SMS_MESSAGING"."DATE_SMS")
```

In order to build the table, my `.sql` file looks like this:

```
-- Create template
CREATE TABLE sms_messaging(
  date_sms DATE primary key,
  result_sms VARCHAR(20),
  msgid VARCHAR(128),
  msgparts INTEGER,
  errorcode INTEGER,
  errormessage VARCHAR(128)
);
```

Even though for this particular `sql_insert` there is no `date_sms`, the error message indicates an issue with this. I don't see where I'm going wrong. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have a column `DATE_SMS` that is declared `NOT NULL` and has no default value.  You need to give it a value.  I don't know what it should be, but perhaps something like this:

```
insert into sms_messaging (result_sms, msgid, msgparts, date_sms)
    values (:1, :2, :3, sysdate);
```

This would put the current date/time into the field.

Comment: Hi thanks, some small improvement but still not resolved. I updated my parameters like you said (though I changed the table so that msgid was the primary key, and the date was omitted). The cursor.execute line works, but after refreshing the SQL Developer Table, the entries are not shown. There were no error messages after the cursor.execute line.

Comment: @pymat . . . You may need to commit the changes.

Comment: @pymat . . . This gets me all the time with Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `DATE_SMS` column is the primary key, and therefore it doesn't accept a `NULL` value.  Since you haven't provided a value in your insert statement for that column, that's why you're getting the error.

I'm not sure about oracle, but in SQL Server, for example, you can setup a default value for a column, so I would, for example, set 'GETDATE()` as the default for a date column.  Maybe Oracle has that too.

Comment: Hi thanks, some small improvement but still not resolved. I updated my parameters like you said (though I changed the table so that msgid was the primary key, and the date was omitted). The cursor.execute line works, but after refreshing the SQL Developer Table, the entries are not shown. There were no error messages after the cursor.execute line.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have `DATE_SMS` as primary key! Rather use `msg_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE sms_messaging(
  date_sms DATE,
  result_sms VARCHAR(20),
  msgid VARCHAR(128) primary key,
  msgparts INTEGER,
  errorcode INTEGER,
  errormessage VARCHAR(128)
);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, some small improvement but still not resolved. I updated my parameters like you said (though I changed the table so that msgid was the primary key, and the date was omitted). The cursor.execute line works, but after refreshing the SQL Developer Table, the entries are not shown. There were no error messages after the cursor.execute line.